# Local DB for development and SQL Azure DB for production

Tags: sql, debugging, azure, configuration, release

I would like to use my local SQL Server for development. I know how to sync data down from SQL Azure to local db. What I'd like is configuration that will allow the debug version to access local db and release version to access SQL Azure. How do I do this?

Comment: Where is the app?  Cloud Service, Web Sites, VM, on-premise?

Answer (score 1):

If your database connection setting is in your web.config file, you can use a web.config transformation. Here is more information about that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx.

If your database connection setting is in a ServiceConfiguration file (if you have a worker role or a web role), you should have at least 2 versions of that file available in your cloud project: ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg and ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg. Place your connection string directly in the appropriate service config file (SQL Server in local and SQL Database in cloud configuration).

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the type of your application there are several ways to reach it:

1. `web.config` transformation is possible for any ASP.NET Application (like suggested by [Herve Roggero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648269/herve-roggero) in another answer), I would recommend to start with [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) for beginning.
2. You can use some predefined symbols to enable conditional compilation of your logic, like:

   ## if DEBUG

   // Open connection to local DB

   ## else

   // Open connection to Azure

   ## endif